# Applying Redux in React native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was creating a simple application which has different API calls, it was working fine until I added a `<Picker />` component which changes state of a value and also changes the API call.

Now I read about Redux and come to a conclusion I must use a middleware for asynchronous calls. This is my second day trying to figure out Redux as it seems confusing to me.

The following is my NetworkService which I used in all components to get the data.

```
import RequestService from './RequestService';

const BASE_URL = 'api.example.com/result';
const ANOT_URL = 'api.example.com/different-result';

const DATE_TODAY = new Date().toISOString();

const PICKER_VALUE = //Here should be the state from which the <Picker /> returns

class NetworkService {
    getResult(){
        let url =`${BASE_URL}/${PICKER_VALUE}`;
        return RequestService.getRequest(url)
    }

    getDifferentResult(){
        let url =`${ANOT_URL}`;
        return RequestService.getRequest(url)
    }

    getResultDate(){
        let url =`${BASE_URL}/${DATE_TODAY}`;
        return RequestService.getRequest(url)
    }
}

export default new NetworkService();
```

RequestService.js

```
class RequestService {
    async getRequest(url) {
        try {
            let response = await (await fetch(url));
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error: ', error);
        }
    }
}
export default new RequestService()
```

I wanted to know if someone can show me how to convert the above into Redux. So i can pass the value from `<Picker />` to the API url, which means having the prop globally.

I attempted multiple times with Redux but it failed, so I found out I had to use `Redux-thunk` but I am still unsure the best way to achieve this.

I found this https://gist.github.com/umayr/4fe94741caa9339292e80e960aa19ff9
But how do I pass to the url the value? Any help appreciated, thank you.

e.g.

```
let url = 'api.example.com/result/${changedValue}' 
//The changedValue is the state chosen from <Picker />
```

Comment: Okay, I'm still having issues myself, but you aren't going to be able to return a promise in redux directly: you'll need to install redux-thunk (or redux-saga, which is even more advanced). With thunk, you'll replace your basic action-creators which currently return a simple object with a "type" and "payload" key. However, this is beyond the scope of a single SO question.

Comment: Yeah, I read about redux-thunk but still trying to figure out about Redux implementations, for best use(as this is my 2nd day using Redux). I'm still reading more about it, if you find a solution to your problem, could you update me please. I'll be testing this for the whole day and if I find a solution I'll update here.

Comment: Here is my project that I'm trying to implement it in: https://github.com/fergusonjason/soccerstats/tree/reduxthunkbranch . Right now, most of my redux/thunk code is in a dedicated /app/redux directory,with the only component I've attempted to modify so far being index.js in DivisionManagement.

Comment: I see, that looks good. I think the Redux terms make it very confusing. Im starting to understand them, but now I have to research Redux thunk middleware.

Comment: I'll be working on it this weekend to try to get it working correctly, then that branch will merge with the main code.

Comment: One thing I'll point out is in the DbUtils.js code. You'll notice that the query() function has a bunch of "await" statements, but redux ignored them. The query2() method is completely promise-based, and seems to work fine with redux and redux-thunk.

Comment: Okay, i'll take it into consideration while trying to implement the method.

Comment: SGhaleb: in case you are looking at that project, that branch has been deleted and all redux/thunk code is now in the main branch of the project.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. I gave up on redux-thunk and moved on to redux-saga as it gave me better control. Thanks anyway